# Parse two words in Persian which are concatenated by half space (\u200c)

Tags: python, farsi

I'm dealing with Persian language poems (The language alphabet is almost the same as Arabic). For each line of the poem in my file, I want to parse its words and hold them in another list as monolithic words. The problem is that some words are separated by space, which I can easily handle with `split()`, but very few are separated by half-space or - `\u200c`.

For example, this is a string in the Persian language:

```
s = "سنگی‌تری"
```

The first word is `"سنگی"` and the second word is `"تری"`. I wanted to separate each of them, but my problem is that I don't know how, and if I use `s.split()`, I get `['سنگی\u200cتری']` which is one word and also has `\u200c`, which should not be. (The two words in `s` are separated by `\u200c` instead of space and this is where the problem arises).

I should also repeat that I need words that are separated by space to be parsed too. So if it was `s = "سنگی ‌تری"` (this time separated by space), I also need to handle it and parse it into `"سنگی"` and `"تری"`. As I said, the latter is achievable by `split()` method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple solution:

```
s.replace("\u200c", " ").split()
```

If you have a longer or more complicated list of boundaries you need to split on, then using [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) would be my recommendation.

Comment: Hello. Thanks. Are you sure it works? I tried it but it gave the whole phrase instead of separating it into two words.

Comment: I tested it with the examples shown in your question, it works with both of those "سنگی‌تری" and "سنگی ‌تری".

Comment: ah yes. I should have written s=s.replace("\u200c", " ").split()

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can either use `re.split`:

```
>>> re.split(" |\u200c", "سنگیتری")
['سنگی', 'تری']
```

Or use `split` twice:

```
>>> [x for full in "سنگیتری".split() for x in full.split("\u200c")]
['سنگی', 'تری']
```

I think I prefer [@wim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65923430/1126841), though.